# Creating a folder in Sdcard fails(samsung Galaxy)

Tags: android

Unable to create a folder in samsung Galaxy .I have tried to create a     folder by just calling this method:
    getting storage path later i am trying to add the folder name to the path and trying to create

```
  Its even showing the path...but no such file was created.

public static String createFolder(String folderName) {
    String extFolName =   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    f = new File(extFolName + "/" + folderName + "/");
    if (f.exists()) {
        path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        return path;
    } else {
        if (f.mkdir()) {
            path = f.getAbsolutePath();
            return path;
        }
 else
 {
 //always going to else don't know y //
    }
    return path;
}
```

when i try to check the folder created in sd card,no file creating...

Comment: Did you give file read write permission?

Comment: What your logcat says?

Comment: What error are you getting? Please write it here.

Comment: are you getting any error? Please paste the logs here.

Comment: no error....but it is always going to else path... that i mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String createFolder(String folderName) {
String extFolName =   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

f = new File(extFolName + "/" + folderName + "/");
if (f.exists()) {
    path = f.getAbsolutePath();
    return path;
} else {
    if (f.mkdirs()) {
        path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        return path;
    }
 else
 {
 //now it will not go to the else part //
 }
return path;
}
```

Comment: try this @Sanjana

Comment: String extFolName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File f = null;
        String path = "";
        f = new File(extFolName + "/" + folderName + "/");
        if (f.exists()) {
            path = f.getAbsolutePath();
            return path;
        } else {
            if (f.mkdirs()) {
                path = f.getAbsolutePath();
                return path;
            }
            else{its going ....no file creating
                Log.e("folder creation", "file not created");
            }
        }
        return path;
    }

Comment: File f= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folderName/");
if(!f.exists())
    mydir.mkdirs();
else
    Log.d("error", "dir. already exists");

Comment: or instead of **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** try /sdcard/myFolder/

Comment: i am able to get the path....from the code...but u know when i try to c manually from mobile i am unable to c it in sd card ....hmmmm

Comment: i am getting the path like /storage/emulated/0/myfoldername but unable to view in it mobile Samsung Galaxy .

Comment: i have manually created a file in mobile ...later i check if exists ...its showing it exists as folder was created manually .....and done with functionality...

Answer (score 0):

Have you following in your `AndroidManfest.xml`.  Also, if you're using Android 6 (API level 23) or later you'll need to request that user accepts that permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: yes i have done it...but still unable to create a folder